# How do I write conda recipes for dynamically linked libraries?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I first wrote a `bash` script to create a `conda` evironment and installs the [xerus](https://www.libxerus.org) library and all of its dependencies.

From this script I then tried to create a `conda` package.
Although it works on my machine (even after uploading to [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/ptrunschke/xerus_salsa)) it does not work for my colleagues.
The `bash` script however does.

I assume that I made a simple mistake in the specification of the `meta.yaml` or `build.sh`.
Can you tell me where I went wrong?

### Install script

```
#!/bin/bash
ENVNAME="${1}"
set -e

if [ -z "${ENVNAME}" ];
then
    echo "Usage: bash install.sh <env_name>"
    exit 0
fi

read -p "Create new conda environment '${ENVNAME}' (y/n)? " answer
case ${answer:0:1} in
    y|Y )
    ;;
    * )
        exit
    ;;
esac

conda create -n ${ENVNAME} -c conda-forge 'python=3.8' python_abi gxx_linux-64 make 'pip>=18.1' numpy openblas suitesparse lapack liblapacke boost-cpp libgomp scipy matplotlib rich
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate ${ENVNAME}
NUMPY=${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy
CXX=${CONDA_PREFIX}/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++

git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/libxerus/xerus.git --branch SALSA
cd xerus

cat <<EOF >config.mk
CXX = ${CXX}
COMPATIBILITY = -std=c++17
COMPILE_THREADS = 8
HIGH_OPTIMIZATION = TRUE
OTHER += -fopenmp

PYTHON3_CONFIG = \`python3-config --cflags --ldflags\`

LOGGING += -D XERUS_LOG_INFO
LOGGING += -D XERUS_LOGFILE
LOGGING += -D XERUS_LOG_ABSOLUTE_TIME
XERUS_NO_FANCY_CALLSTACK = TRUE

BLAS_LIBRARIES = -lopenblas -lgfortran
LAPACK_LIBRARIES = -llapacke -llapack
SUITESPARSE = -lcholmod -lspqr
BOOST_LIBS = -lboost_filesystem

OTHER += -I${CONDA_PREFIX}/include -I${NUMPY}/core/include/
OTHER += -L${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib
EOF

ln -s ${CONDA_PREFIX}/include/ ${CONDA_PREFIX}/include/suitesparse
make python
python -m pip install . --no-deps -vv

cd ..
rm -rf xerus
```

### conda-build files

#### meta.yaml

```
{% set name = "Xerus" %}
{% set version = "4.0.1" %}
{% set branch = "SALSA" %}

package:
  name: {{ name|lower + '_' + branch|lower }}
  version: {{ version }}

source:
  - git_url: https://github.com/libxerus/xerus.git
    git_tag: {{ branch }}
    folder: xerus

build:
  number: 1
  skip: true       # [py<34 or win]
  run_exports:
    - python_abi
    - numpy
    - openblas
    - suitesparse
    - lapack
    - liblapacke
    - boost-cpp
    - libgomp

requirements:
  build:
    - {{ compiler('cxx') }}
    - make
    - python {{ python }}
    - pip >=18.1
  host:
    - python_abi
    - numpy
    - openblas
    - suitesparse
    - lapack
    - liblapacke
    - boost-cpp
    - libgomp
  run:
    - python_abi
    - numpy
    - openblas
    - suitesparse
    - lapack
    - liblapacke
    - boost-cpp
    - libgomp

test:
  files:
    - VERSION

about:
  home: https://libxerus.org
  license: "AGPL 3.0"
  license_file: LICENSE
  summary: "A c++ library for numerical calculations with higher order tensors"
  description: |
    The Xerus library is a general purpose library for numerical calculations with higher order tensors, Tensor-Train Decompositions / Matrix Product States and other Tensor Networks.
    The focus of development was the simple usability and adaptibility to any setting that requires higher order tensors or decompositions thereof.
  doc_url: https://libxerus.org/doxygen
  dev_url: https://github.com/libxerus/xerus
```

#### build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x -e

cd xerus

cat <<EOF >config.mk
CXX = ${CXX}
COMPATIBILITY = -std=c++17
COMPILE_THREADS = 8
HIGH_OPTIMIZATION = TRUE
OTHER += -fopenmp

PYTHON3_CONFIG = \`python3-config --cflags --ldflags\`

LOGGING += -D XERUS_LOG_INFO
LOGGING += -D XERUS_LOGFILE
LOGGING += -D XERUS_LOG_ABSOLUTE_TIME
XERUS_NO_FANCY_CALLSTACK = TRUE

BLAS_LIBRARIES = -lopenblas -lgfortran
LAPACK_LIBRARIES = -llapacke -llapack
SUITESPARSE = -lcholmod -lspqr
BOOST_LIBS = -lboost_filesystem

OTHER += -I${PREFIX}/include -I${PREFIX}/lib/python${PY_VER}/site-packages/numpy/core/include/
OTHER += -L${PREFIX}/lib
EOF

ln -s ${PREFIX}/include/ ${PREFIX}/include/suitesparse
make python
${PYTHON} -m pip install . --no-deps -vv
```

#### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

VERSION=$(cat VERSION)

export PYTHONPATH=''

${PYTHON} <<EOF
print("="*80)
print("\trun_test.sh for Xerus ${VERSION}")
print("="*80)
import xerus
assert xerus.__version__ == '${VERSION}', xerus.__version__+" != ${VERSION}"
EOF
```

Comment: What is the error that occurs on your colleague's machine?

Comment: He gets `OSError: libboost_filesystem.so.1.75.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Comment: It's not obvious what's going wrong.  Since you have properly specified `boost-cpp` in the `run:` requirements and included `-L${PREFIX}/lib` in the build flags, I would expect `libboost_filesystem` to be located correctly.

Comment: One odd thing I noticed is that the [xerus Makefile](https://git.hemio.de/xerus/xerus/-/blob/master/Makefile) doesn't actually use `BOOST_LIBS`.  As far as I can tell, that variable is having no effect.  Is that right?  I must be missing something because if that were true, then I don't really see how the build requires `boost_filesystem` at all...

Comment: It may be useful to run `ldd ${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/libxerus.so` on your own machine, to inspect the specific version of `libboost_filesystem.so` it uses.  If it's not using the one from your conda environment, that's a problem.  Of course, that doesn't tell you WHY it chose the wrong version.  Since I see no obvious problems with your conda recipe, I'm starting to suspect that there's a subtle error in the xerus Makefile itself.  But it's difficult to say for sure.

Comment: `BOOST_LIBS` is used in the [Makefile](https://git.hemio.de/xerus/xerus/-/blob/SALSA/Makefile) of the `SALSA` branch. The `master` branch still uses a different Makefile.
`ldd ${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xerus/libxerus_misc.so` shows that `libboost_filesystem.so.1.75.0` is linked against the correct version of `libboost_filesystem.so`.

Comment: The current Makefile is indeed bizarre. We don't install `libxerus.so` and `libxerus_misc.so` into `${PREFIX}/lib` but copy them to `${PREFIX}/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xerus/` and use a [trick](https://git.hemio.de/xerus/xerus/-/blob/SALSA/xerus/__init__.py) to load them when `xerus` is imported.
I can't imagine why this should result in the stated problem but I will try to change this behaviour tomorrow.

Comment: Miraculously, removing this trick worked. Thank you for your support.
Should I delete the question since I don't know why my modifications fixed the problem?

Comment: I wonder if, for some reason, conda-build had trouble editing the RPATH within your libraries.  Normally it ensures that the RPATH is specified as a relative path, so it will continue working on other machines (as long as the structure of the PREFIX remains intact).

Comment: Regarding deletion: I know opinions may differ, but I see no harm in leaving it up.  Maybe it would be worth providing an answer below, stating what you found.  Anyone who's really desperate for clues related to a similar problem can read our discussion.